# Spatial profile for a superconducting qubit's wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

What is a spatial profile for a wavefunction of a superconducting qubit (such as say a flux qubit, charge qubit, or a transmon)?

I am trying to calculate the energy shift of an superconducting qubit (say a charge qubit for the sake of discussion) coupled to a multi-mode field inside a transmission line. When dealing with a real atom, normally in order to avoid divergences, instead of treating the atom as a single point, one considers the spatial profile of its wavefunction (and then the Fourier transform of that can be used that effectively provides a natural frequency "cutoff"). For an atom it seems to make sense to take a look at a given orbital and think of the atom's "size" in terms of it.

Is there any literature on the equivalent for superconducting qubits? Since we usually think of the superconducting qubit's degrees of freedom in terms of the flux/charge (or equivalently phase/Cooper-pair-number) , it is not obvious to me what the physical "size" of these wave functions would be? Most naive way might be to think about say the size of the loop (for a flux qubit) or size of the "island" (for a charge qubit), but I would like to know if anyone knows of published discussions on this topic.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you require a reference to published literature or would my own answer suffice?

Comment: any answer would be great of course... if you have references that would be even better, but your answer would be a good start. thanks.

Comment: Ok, are you familiar with the electromagnetic mode profile of a transmission line or wire?